# OpenLayers Icon does not show up

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file. I have a Thymeleaf that shows a map with OpenLayers 4 library with an Icon, but the Icon does not show up anywhere in the map

```
<div id="Map" class="map"></div>
<div id="popup"></div>
<div></div>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/

  var lat = /*[[${lat}]]*/ ;
  var lng = /*[[${lng}]]*/ ;

  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([lng, lat]),
    name: 'The icon',
    population: 4000,
    rainfall: 500
  });

  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png'
    }))
  });

  iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature]
  });

  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });

  var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
      url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json?secure',
      crossOrigin: ''
    })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer,
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'Map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: {
        collapsible: false
      }
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lng, lat]),
      zoom: 14
    })
  });
  /*]]>*/

</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

1. you haven't projected the coordinates to the correct projection:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
  name: 'The icon',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});
```

2. Once I do that the icon appears briefly then disappears unless I change this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: 'Map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: false
    }
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lng, lat]),
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/29buv8f0/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

If you don't want the `'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json?secure'` tiles, change:

```
var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
    url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json?secure',
    crossOrigin: ''
  })
});
```

To:

```
var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/29buv8f0/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var lat = 42;
var lng = -75;

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
  name: 'The icon',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png'
  }))
});

iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: 'Map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: false
    }
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lng, lat]),
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="Map" class="map"></div>
<div id="popup"></div>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
```